# Dedupe rule ignores the location type for Email/Phone but does not ignore for Addresses. Should we make this consistent

Tags: duplicate-contacts, dedupe-rules

per the title, what do others think is the better behaviour

a/ ignore Location Type for Email, Phone, but use Location Type for Address (status quo)

b/ change so Location Type is never taken in to consideration (ie Address would be treated same as Email, Phone)

c/ change so Email/Phone also have Location Type taken in to consideration when applying matching rules.

Reason for asking is we got caught out using a rule with postcode. We expected the postcode to be location agnostic. Seems it isn't.

Answer (score 5):

B please. This has been a point of frustration when importing. Make the location type simply a label without deduping consideration.

I thought it always takes into account location type.

Comment: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17645 implements this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code this was implemented in svn days & it's just a case of removing code & adding a unit test

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/2cbe6e87cbf0c1ce7a2f89c2000c472b58e66146/CRM/Dedupe/Finder.php#L266-L298

Relevant tickets:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17564 https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-5026 https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-3902

From the code it looks like this is used when matching on creating a contact but not on finding duplicate contacts from the finder screen.

I'm +1 on B but would want to see more people weigh in (esp as I'm not a heavy user of this functionality as we import and then dedupe for historical reasons - which by-passes this)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this today and am also a +1 for B.  I think the Bs have it.